# How to use result from one async function to another

Tags: javascript, function, async-await, geolocation, fetch

I am trying to use the latitude and longitude coordinates on an ISS api (https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544) in the url of another api (https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/coordinates/37.795517,-122.393693). I am trying to use the coordinates and input them in the url instead of using the hard coded ones.

**This is what I have done so far...**

- I have tried using a template string to make the coordinates dynamic: `https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/coordinates/${latitude},${longitude}`
- I have made two separate async await functions: (1) getISS() to get the lat/ lon coordinates and (2) getGeoLocation() to take those coordinates and get the country_code/ timecode_id data
- I have also tried calling the getGeoLocation() with latitude,longitude as arguments and passing them into latitude and longitude for the parameters, but this only results in a 500 error

**Note**

- I know both url api's work because I have tested them and received the data I was looking for
- This is the api website https://wheretheiss.at/w/developer

```js
const api_url_id = 'https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/satellites/25544'

//async await getISS function
async function getISS() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url_id)
    const data = await response.json()
    const {
        latitude,
        longitude,
        velocity,
        visibility
    } = data
}

async function getGeoLocation(latitude, longitude) {
    const response2 = await fetch(`https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/coordinates/${latitude},${longitude}`)
    const data2 = await response2.json()
    const {
        timezone_id,
        country_code
    } = data2

    console.log(data2.timezone_id,country_code)
}

getGeoLocation(data.latitude, data.longitude)

getISS()
```

Comment: The second request getting a 500 internal server error with certain lats and longs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**async** functions returns a **promise**, so you can use **.then()**

You should return the data from *getISS* and use **.then()**, like this...

```
// getISS function returns data
async function getISS() {
  const response = await fetch(api_url_id);
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
}
```

Call your *getISS* function, using *then* to later call *getGeoLocation* with the necessary data

```
getISS().then(({ latitude, longitude }) => {
  getGeoLocation(latitude, longitude);
});
```

Comment: I've tried that and I am able to use the coordinates in the getGeoLocation. However, i am still getting an error: requests.js:18 GET https://api.wheretheiss.at/v1/coordinates/9.5681067472009,52.415544151319 500 (Internal Server Error)
getGeoLocation @ requests.js:18
(anonymous) @ requests.js:32
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ requests.js:28
requests.js:24 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Unable to fetch ISS data
    at getGeoLocation (requests.js:24)

Comment: Yep, I noticed that. If you try with other coordinates, works. So, your code now its ok. Maybe the service is giving you wrong coordinates, or the getGeoLocation just gives 500 with certain (restricted) coordinates

Comment: I figured out that if the coordinates are over a body of water it gives an error. So frustrating, but I figured it out eventually!